# How to skip records that turn on/off the range pattern?

Tags: gawk

```
gawk '/<Lexer>/,/<\/Lexer>/' file
```

this works but it prints the first and last records, which I'd like to omit. How to do so?

It says: "The record that turns on the range pattern and the one that turns it off both match the range pattern. If you don't want to operate on these records, you can write if statements in the rule's action to distinguish them from the records you are interested in." but no example.
I tried something like
    `gawk '/<Lexer>/,/<\/Lexer>/' {1,FNR-1} file`
 but it doesn't work.
If you have a better way to do this, without using awk, say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with 2 separate match statements and a variable

```
gawk '/<Lexer>/{p=1; next} /<\/Lexer>/ {p=0} p==1 {print}' file
```

This matches `<Lexer>` and sets p to 1 and then skips to the next line. While p is 1 it prints the current line. When it matches `</Lexer>` it sets p to 0 and skips. As p is 0 printing is suppressed.